# How do I use expo-task-manager to open a website in the background in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm coding in react native and I want to use expo-task-manager to open a webbrowser in the device background by calling my function. I want to open a webbrowser in the background of the device headlessly.

My code so far is:

```
// Note the additional import of useEffect
import React, { useState, useEffect,  useRef  } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { BackgroundFetchResult } from 'expo-background-fetch';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    _handlePressButtonAsync();
  }, []);

  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://vitech-104517.square.site/');
    setResult(result);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Website will open automatically</Text>
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```